# Is there a strict maximum or minimum bound for Big O and Big Omega notation? What is a tight bound?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

If Big O notation describes the upper bound of a function, can't most functions have an upper bound of $O(n!)$?

Example:

$f(x) = x^2+6x+9$

If we let $g(x) = n!$, then:

$\forall n\ge 5$, $f(x) \le cg(x)$

I have effectively proved that $f(x) = O(g(x!))$<strike>, and the same reasoning can be applied for Big Omega</strike> . But this isn't right, since I know $f(x) = O(g(x))$ for $cg(x) = 5x^2$ and $n\ge 3$.

So my question is, what defines the "tight bound" for Big O/Omega notation? For the above example, why do we almost always describe $f(x)$ as $O(n^2)$? What makes my reasoning wrong?

Edit: It isn't possible to prove $f(x) = \Omega(n!)$, so I removed that part of my question.

Comment: How do you prove it for $\Omega$?

Comment: @CrackedBauxite You're right, I can't. I'm not sure why I thought that. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of functions *are* $O(n!)$. Every polynomial, for instance. But something like $2^{2^n}$ is not $O(n!)$ (do you see why?). Notice that $n^2 + 6n + 9$ is *not* $\Omega(n!)$, as it looks like you're claiming.

When I was an undergrad, we were very careful on homework to write "give a *tight* big O bound for the runtime of this algorithm" in order to prevent smart alec students from making exactly this argument :P. After all, they could probably write $O(n!)$ for everything and never be wrong.

This gives two natural follow up questions:

1. Why allow this ambiguity?

The answer is "because it's useful". Sometimes we *don't* know for sure what the perfect upper bound is, so it's nice to be able to say $O(n^2 \log n)$ in the preliminary paper, and be correct, even if we're pretty sure the $\log n$ factor can be removed with more work. People in the real world *aren't* trying to game the system in this way, so we don't worry about it.

2. What if we *do* know the bound is tight? Can we notate that?

The answer is "yes", and there are two choices.

The first is "big Theta", where $f = \Theta(g)$ if and only if $f = O(g)$ and $f = \Omega(g)$. That is, if $f = \Theta(g)$, we know that (eventually) $\frac{1}{C} g \leq f \leq C g$ for some constant $C$. So we know the dominant behavior of $f$ precisely, modulo the exact constant out front.

The second doesn't have a great name (as far as I know), but we write $f \sim g$ to mean that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f}{g} = 1$. That is, $f$ and $g$ get more and more similar for larger and larger inputs. It might not be as clear from the definition, but $f \sim g$ tells us that we know the dominant asymptotics *and* the constant term!

For instance, we have

- $4n^3 + 2n + 7 = \Theta(n^3)$
- $4n^3 + 2n + 7 \neq \Theta(n^4)$
- $4n^3 + 2n + 7 \not \sim n^3$
- $4n^3 + 2n + 7 \sim 4n^3$

As a quick exercise, can you show that $f \sim g$ implies $f = \Theta(g)$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Wikipedia mentions "on the order of" for $f \sim g$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations

Comment: I usually read "$f \sim g$" as "$f$ is asymptotically equivalent to $g$"; e.g. see the [Asymptotic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) Wikipedia page.